# Cannot loop over subdirectories in simple bash script

Tags: bash, shell

This is my very short shell script (no shebang, really just this):

```
MYPATH=/home/robert/fatherdir

for d in $MYPATH/*/; do
    echo "$d"
done
```

When I execute that script, I get this echo output on the terminal **instead** of the subdirectories `childirectory` and `childfolder`:

```
/home/robert/fatherdir/*/
```

I've been on this for about 3 hours now and it's driving me nuts by now because I have the **exact** same code (including the spaces!) in a cronjob script and it works in there! Meaning, the subdirectories get succesfully looped. Cronjob uses /bin/sh which I also use to execute my testing script. /bin/sh is gnu bash 4.4.23

Comment: Your code will write the directory names under `/home/robert/fatherdir`, one per line, for example `/home/robert/fatherdir/apple/`, `/home/robert/fatherdir/pear/`. Or if there are no directories it will write `/home/robert/fatherdir/*/`. What do you get with `ls -F /home/robert/fatherdir`? Please [edit] your question to include this

Comment: You should _always_ provide a `#!` line as the first line of your script. In your case it seems you would want `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Basically it was a permission error without getting the feedback of it being a permission problem. The fatherdir is on a NFS share. I've changed it here to provide a very basic example, not knowing that I would take out the important part of the problem. cronjob runs as root and has access to the share, user robert doesn't. When I execute the script, I do not see "permission denied" (it's silent, nasty trap). You've sparked that idea with your "or if there are no directories" - thank you so much! Executing the testing script as root shows the expected behaviour.

Comment: `shopt -s failglob` can make the trap less silent.